# Google sheet scripts runs right manually but setting triggers does not work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send texts on a time trigger on a google sheet using Twilio to send the texts. When I click the run button it works fine but when I set up a time trigger it says its in status it's completed but does not work. Also when I click on Executions I do get an error it says "Exception: Request failed for https://api.twilio.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number  is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "status": 400} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"

I'm 100% new to Java and am learning about it any help would be great.

Here is my Code:

```
function RunThisToSendTexts() {
function sendSms(to, body) {
 var messagesUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC9837381a431941024fc87xxxxxx/Messages.json";
 
 var payload = {
 "To": to,
 "Body" : body,
 "From" : "+197131999xx"
};
  var options = {
 "method" : "post",
 "payload" : payload
};
  options.headers = {   
 "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("AC9837381a431941024fcxxxxxxx:22c7dec97dee0cef39exxxxxxx")
};
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(messagesUrl, options);
}
 
function sendAll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
 for (i in data) {
 var row = data[i];
 try {
   response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
   status = "sent";
 } catch(err) {
   Logger.log(err);
   status = "error";
 }
 sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
 }
}
 
 sendAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it like this:

```
function sendSms(to, body) {
 var messagesUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC9837381a431941024fc87xxxxxx/Messages.json";
 
 var payload = {
 "To": to,
 "Body" : body,
 "From" : "+197131999xx"
};
  var options = {
 "method" : "post",
 "payload" : payload
};
  options.headers = {   
 "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("AC9837381a431941024fcxxxxxxx:22c7dec97dee0cef39exxxxxxx")
};
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(messagesUrl, options);
}

function sendAll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
 for (i in data) {
 var row = data[i];
 try {
   response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
   status = "sent";
 } catch(err) {
   Logger.log(err);
   status = "error";
 }
 sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
 }
}
```

And just run sendAll();

Try sendAll() this way:

```
function sendAll() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 2;
  const data = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var status = 'Error'
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    sendSms(r[0], r[1]);
    status = 'sent';
  });
  sh.getRange(i + sr, 3).setValue(status);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and i get this error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.twilio.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code": 21604, "message": "A 'To' phone number is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604", "status": 400} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
sendSms @ Code.gs:16

Comment: Are you getting this still: `"The 'To' number is not a valid phone number.",`

Comment: I am not when I use yours I get the phone number is required. so its like it cant find the phone number in the sheet. I have column A as the phone number and B is the Message I want to send to that number

Comment: The sendAll works when I run it manually but when I set up a trigger for it to run it I still get the "Not a Valid Phone Number". I've changed the numbers to what twilio specifies thats using E.164 formatting. I've even tried standard phone number formatting and using () in the numbers. I'm starting to think this is more a google issue than twilio. It worked find until about a week ago and haven't made any changes until todayl